# R lattice bar chart: choose order of bars?

Tags: r, lattice

My data looks like this:

```
service,rating_1,rating_2,rating_3,rating_4,rating_5
renew_patent,0,0,1,2,11
apply_benefit,21,20,121,828,1744
apply_employment_tribunal,0,0,0,0,0
```

I want R to print me a histogram for each row, with the columns as the bars of the histogram.

I've got this so far:

```
require(lattice)
data <- read.csv("test.csv", header = TRUE)
colors = c('red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green')
barchart(rating_1+rating_2+rating_3+rating_4+rating_5 ~ service, data=data, 
  auto.key=list(space='right'), scales=list(x=list(rot=45)), 
  ylab="Percentage of total", col=colors)
```

It's working, but it's printing the histogram with bars in alphabetical order, not the order they're specified in the CSV file.

How can I change this so the bars are in the order in the CSV file, with `renew_patent` first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the order of the levels in the data itself, then `barchart` will do what you want.

One option would be to run code like:

```
data$service <- factor(data$service, levels=unique( as.character(data$service) ) )
```

before calling `barchart`.

Comment: Yeap, or you can even specify manually the order: data$service <- ordered(data$service, levels = c("renew_patent", "apply_benefit", "apply_employment_tribunal"))

Comment: Unfortunately if I then plug `data$service` into the `barchart` command, I get `Error in eval(substitute(groups), data, environment(formula)) : numeric 'envir' arg not of length one`.

Comment: @Richard how did you "plug it in?" You shouldn't have to change anything in your `barchart` call. "service" is already there as a member of data. You just need to run this line before you call `barchart`